# Powershell won't find equal for $var in csv file

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty new to powershell and I'm trying to assign Exchange-groups and shared mailboxes with an Powershell script. I have a .csv file with the job title, department and all the associated groups and mailboxes. I wrote the following script to achieve my goal but it doesn't work.
I have the feeling that the `Where {$_.JobTitle -eq $JOBcsv -and $_.Department -eq $DEPcsv}` part is making the script fail. If I put a text value like 'Accountmanager' instead of $JOBcsv all works fine. Thanks in advance!

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $cred
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $cred

$User=Read-Host -Prompt 'Write UPN'
$DEPcsv=Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $User | Select Department
$JOBcsv=Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $User | Select JobTitle


$Groups = Import-CSV -Path "C:\PS Scripts\Groepen en Mailboxen.csv" -Delimiter ";"  | Where {$_.JobTitle -eq $JOBcsv -and $_.Department -eq $DEPcsv} | Select Groepen
ForEach ($item in $Groups)
{Add-DistributiongroupMember $item -Member $User}
    
         
$Mailboxes = Import-CSV -Path "C:\PS Scripts\Groepen en Mailboxen.csv" -Delimiter ";" | Where {$_.JobTitle -eq $JOBcsv -and $_.Department -eq $DEPcsv} | Select Mailboxen
ForEach ($item in $Mailboxes)        
{Add-MailboxPermission $item -user $User -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All}
```

Comment: Change `Select Department` to `ForEach-Object Department` and change `Select JobTitle` to `ForEach-Object JobTitle`

Comment: @Theo The $Gebruiker should be $User, I forgot it while translaiting.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanx for you're comment! It helped a lot! The csv cel called in Groups contanains multible groups formatted like "Group1","Group2","Group3". The ForEach stament in ```ForEach ($item in $Groups)``` is not making the value behind $Groups be treated as seprate items.

Comment: Try `Select -ExpandProperty Department`. (Same for jobtitle)

Comment: @Midaviezert 1 CSV field/cell = 1 string. You need to split it up if it contains multiple values, eg `foreach($item in $Groups -split ',\s*')`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you! All working now!